# Flutter convert xlsx to List<Object>

Tags: excel, flutter, xlsx

I have an xlsx excel table and I need to convert it into a `List<Object>` and take just the following columns: **D, F, H, J, L**. I'm trying everything but nothing works.

I'm using the following plugin to do it:

- [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)
- [excel](https://pub.dev/packages/excel)

Does anyone know how can I convert it?

[Table](https://www.sendspace.com/file/f4a1dw)

Here is my example code:

```dart
import 'package:adminpanelweb/models/import_users.dart';
import 'package:excel/excel.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future importUsers(BuildContext context, String palaceId) async {
  FilePickerResult? pickedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
    allowMultiple: false,
  );

  if (pickedFile != null) {
    var bytes = pickedFile.files.single.bytes;
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes!);
    List<ImportUsers> users = [];
    List<String> stringList = [];
    for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
      for (var rows in excel.tables[table]!.rows) {
        // print(
        //   '${rows.toString().isNotEmpty ? rows.map((e) => e?.value).toList() : ''}',
        // );

        stringList.add(
            '${rows.toString().isNotEmpty ? rows.map((e) => e?.value).toList() : ''}');
      }
    }
    final regExp = RegExp(r'(?:\[)?(\[[^\]]*?\](?:,?))(?:\])?');
    final input = stringList.toString();
    final result = regExp
        .allMatches(input)
        .map((m) => m.group(1))
        .map((String? item) => item?.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\[\]]'), ''))
        .map((m) => [m])
        .toList();

    for (var items in result) {
      users = items.map((e) {
        return {
          "field1": e?[0],
          "WEB": e?[1],
          "R": e?[2],
          "Denominazione": e?[3],
          "Data Uscita": e?[4],
          "Codice Fiscale": e?[5],
          "Partita IVA": e?[6],
          "Username": e?[7],
          "field9": e?[8],
          "Password": e?[9],
          "Profilo": e?[10],
          "Email": e?[11],
        };
      }).toList() as List<ImportUsers>;
      print(items);
    }
    // print('sadasdasdasdsad ${users.length}');
  }
}
```

After some hours I solved as it:

```dart
Future importUsers(BuildContext context, String palaceId) async {
  FilePickerResult? pickedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
    allowMultiple: false,
  );

  if (pickedFile != null) {
    List<User> xlsxToList = [];
    var bytes = pickedFile.files.single.bytes;
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes!);

    for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
      for (var row in excel.tables[table]!.rows) {
        xlsxToList.add(
          User(
            userEmail: row[11]?.value.toString(),
            userUsername: row[7]?.value.toString(),
            userName: row[3]?.value.toString(),
            userCf: row[5]?.value.toString(),
            userPassword: row[9]?.value.toString(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    xlsxToList.removeAt(0);
    print('__________ ${userToJson(xlsxToList)}');
  }
}
```

Comment: the table file seems to be deleted

Comment: What are some of the things you tried? Post some code.

Comment: @MendelG solved

Comment: @RichardHeap posted, sorry